# Daylight saving time in .net

Tags: .net, time, timezone, dst

I am working on an ASP.NET application.

I want to know how to check if a specific date lies in the Daylight Saving Time period in Australia.

For example, I want to check `12/12/2013 12:30PM` is in Daylight Saving Time in Australia or not.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to know the specific time zone you are talking about.  Australia has 5 major time zones, and 13 discrete entries in the TZDB.  You can read more [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_in_australia).

For the conversion, use [`TimeZoneInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.aspx), or [Noda Time](http://www.nodatime.org).

You should also read the [timezone tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info).

If you can be more specific, and show code for what you have tried, I will update this answer with a more detailed response.

Answer (score 0):

NodaTime library by Jon Skeet exposes Tzdb as one of the DateTimeZoneProviders.

```
public void Test_NodaTime_IsDaylightSavingTime()
{
    var ts = new DateTime(1980, 4, 15, 12, 0, 0);
    var local = LocalDateTime.FromDateTime(ts);
    var zdt = Utils.TzEast.ResolveLocal(local, Utils.CustomResolver);
    Assert.IsFalse(zdt.IsDaylightSavingTime());
}
```

https://www.timehubzone.com/time/zones